# Move Other(Like whatsapp, facebook) Application Internal Memory to External Storage Programmatically

Tags: android

I want to create application which can directly move third application from internal storage application to external storage from our app.

Example:
I want to move WhatsApp internal storage to external storage.
and My application name "APPSMover". Then through APPSMover WhatsApp move internal to external storage. I don't wan't to go Application Info page and don't want press "Move to Sdcard" button.

I want to Move programmatically WhatsApp and any other app from internal storage to external storage.

If anyone have suggestion please let me know.

Comment: This community offers help with solving problems regarding to actual Android development. We don't create code for you.

Comment: I am not asking for the  code. I am asking for some help, idea or tips.

Comment: "Please give me solution as soon as possible. Thank you.". You should do your own research first, that way you'll learn the most.

Comment: yes i am doing my research that's why I ask the question.

Comment: @hardik.ramoliya did you mean move functionality like cleanmaster app?

Comment: @TimKranen but what about all answers on SO which have created code? Didn't you confused Stack*Overflow* with Stack*Exchange*? I think it so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible without root permissions. Apps which are installed on the SD card have certain limitations so I suspect the system won't allow an app to move another app to the SD card (therefore limiting its functionality).

As far as I know, the "move to sdcard" feature was deprecated some time ago (i guess since Android 4). Most modern android devices don't support it anyway. Different install locations can cause some trouble with third-party software although some old devices (around 2.2) might still benefit from the feature as those tend to have very limited internal memory.

In my opinion, you are wasting your time. There is a small and shrinking group of users who need the feature at all. The primary reason to move apps is to free internal storage, so it does not appear clever to install an additional app just to save a click when moving an app. As I understood it, you basically want to skip the app info screen and clicking the button "move to sdcard". Again, I don't think this is possible using standard APIs and permissions and even if it was, it would be a waste of time.